# ExtJS: how can we get the size of the store in a grid

Tags: extjs, grid, size, store

I am trying to get the size of the store I am using in the grid.
But I am not able to find any method to get the size of the store(number of records in the grid).

Could anyone plz help, how can I achieve this.

Thanks,
Neha

Answer (score 11):

there is getCount() method to get the number of elements in the store.

Comment: Well, you should have looked before asking, but you have your answer. grid.getStore().getCount() is ok.

Answer (score 9):

`store.data.length` will give you the number of records.